# How to manage sub-project versioning within large (Gradle) project?

Tags: versioning, gradle

I have a large Gradle project (2+m LOC) with many sub-projects (50-60). I’d like to be able to version each of the sub-projects separately so that they can be published or released independently. Some of the projects depend on each other, e.g. `libA` may be depended on by `project1` and `project2`.

I’m interested in whether there is a good way (via a plugin, perhaps) for manage the versioning the projects such that when a change is made to `libA` that the version number for `libA`, `project1`, `project2` and any other downstream project dependencies all have their respective version incremented.

If I apply the same version to all subprojects then even though there may be changes to only one project which is not depended on by any other project, when I publish the build artifacts then I need to publish an artifact for every project (i.e. 50-60).

I appreciate this is a bit of an open-ended question, but the approach we have now (using the axion-release-plugin is too slow because of the size of the codebase and the number of projects), so I’m interested in any other approaches to versioning within multi-module Gradle projects that other teams may be using successfully. The one constraint I have is that I am not able to split up the monorepo into separate projects.

Comment: I'm looking also at something similar, my first thought is to use composite builds. What have you done in the meanwhile?